# Terminate Service By executing PowerShell script from Java

Tags: java, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell script using Java Runtime class, but for some reason nothing happens. I'm also trying to get CMD output to my Java code but without success. This is my code:

```java
private void connectToServer() {
    executeCmdCommand("cd C:/PSTools");// navigate to psTools directory
    executeCmdCommand("PsExec.exe //<server1> -u orgnization/user_qa -p      sdsad1212 cmd");// connect the server machine
    executeCmdCommand("powershell.exe C:/powerShell/stop-process.ps1 MainRls");// stopr service by execute powershell script
}

/**
* execute cmd commands
*/
private void executeCmdCommand(String command){
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        Report.assertOnReport(inputStream.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I execute the same commands from CMD manually the service terminated successfully, but it's doing nothing when executed by Java code.

Comment: Have you checked PowerShell script execution policy? Default setting require signed scripts. Open Powershell prompt and type: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` or `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 2):

The commands work when you manually execute them, because the second command opens an interactive shell on the remote host and you're typing the third command into that shell *on the remote host.* Your Java code doesn't work that way, as it runs both commands individually. Hence you need to run the PowerShell command directly with `PsExec`:

```java
executeCmdCommand("PsExec.exe //<server1> -u orgnization/user_qa -p sdsad1212 C:/windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -File C:/powerShell/stop-process.ps1 MainRls");
```

Comment: I Tried it, but it does not execute Powershell script after connecting the server

Comment: Then it's probably because my answer had unescaped backslashes in a path. I replaced them with forward slashes. Please try again.